# Solving three linear equations in terms of unknown

Tags: linear-algebra

$$\alpha+\beta+\gamma=a$$
$$\alpha+\beta=b$$
$$\gamma=c$$

Find the values of $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ in terms of $a,b,c$

Obviously, the value of $\gamma$ is $c$

So after eliminating $\gamma$ from first two equations, I get
$$\alpha+\beta=a-c$$
$$\alpha+\beta=b$$
Here I do not know how to find $\alpha,\beta$

The answer given is $\alpha=a-b-2c,\beta=b-c$

Comment: The given answer implies that $c=0$ and $a=b$, but $(a,b,c)=(3,2,1)$ gives infinitely many solutions (the system becomes equivalent to $\alpha + \beta = 2$).

Comment: @mathh so do you mean that this question have problem?

Comment: The answer implies that the system of equations, where $a,b,c$ are constants, can only have solutions when $c=0, a=b$, but I've given a counterexample where it has infinitely many solutions and $c\neq 0$, so the answer is wrong, if the question and the answer are as stated here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original system of equations is equivalent to $\begin{cases}\alpha+\beta=a-c\\\alpha+\beta=b\\\phi=c\end{cases}\iff \begin{cases}\alpha+\beta=b\\b+c=a\\\phi=c\end{cases}\iff \begin{cases}\alpha=\beta-b\\b+c=a\\\phi=c\end{cases}$.

The only equation where $\beta$ acts is in the expression of $\alpha$. Therefore, $\alpha$ **must** depend on $\beta$ and you cannot express it purely in terms of $a,b,c$.